# make my theme /site max width of 960 instead of current 1170

Tags: css

Hi I have a site that was built with a wordpress tempalte called celistino just want to ask how would I achieve that my site max-width would be 960 regardless of the resolution of the computer / monitor we are using. The current theme was http://demo.yithemes.com/celestino/ and it's made on max-width bootstrap 1170 grid, I would want to make it 960 maxwidth.

Upon looking it is supporting 1170px responsive layout, we need to achieved the it would only be 960 rather than its standard 1170. Looking forward for any response Thanks in Advance

Thanks

Comment: You have to add your css file(css code like css in my answer) after bootstrap css. then it will work fine.

Comment: I've tested it again but nothing happened.

Comment: See my Answer. I edit it. try it. I am sure it will work.

Comment: Thanks Jamir I've seen and tested the new code, it worked at some point but the layout was distorted and the sidebar went off you can see the screenshots here http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/42/40616639.png/ and http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/1079/62317619.png sidebar should be align with the content but it went down, also the footter contents are rumbled. Thanks

Comment: you have to add css for sidebars also in below code write in my answer

Comment: Thanks Jamir, but should the body width be resized in orde to fit in the sidebar and also same as the menus?

Comment: You can add css whatever you want in media query.

Comment: Thank you! it kinda working a bit, just need to know how to resize the portfolio images to 220px by 150px so it woud match the 960px layout.  Any Ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to customize css3 media-queries in bootstrap-responsive.css. It will work fine. like following code:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

  .container,
  .navbar-static-top .container,
  .navbar-fixed-top .container,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
    width: 960px;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks, I've tried it but didnt work, the urrent max-width set by the bootstrap was 1170px

Comment: I've tested it again but nothing happened

Comment: If you want help you should atleast do your best to get us enough information to help you. We have no code nor have we any reason WHY "nothing happens". "Nothing happens" is not a specific description of a problem.

Comment: Thanks Jamir I've seen and tested the new code, it worked at some point but the layout was distorted and the sidebar went off you can see the screenshots here imageshack.us/photo/my-images/42/40616639.png and img831.imageshack.us/img831/1079/62317619.png sidebar should be align with the content but it went down, also the footter contents are rumbled. Thanks

Comment: you have to add css for sidebars also in below code in my answer